# Condition from matches in two column Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am working on a excel like this

[image]

I would like to create a condition from second table using matches between two tables columns values (Tool and tools) to automatically replace the column Unit prince

I want this result

```
<table>
| Tool | United Price |
| : ---|:------------:|
| Axe  | 5,9          |
| : ---|:------------:|
| Axe  | 5,9          |
| : ---|:------------:|
| Hoe  | 9,1          |
| : ---|:------------:|
| Drill| 7,8          |
| : ---|:------------:|
| Hoe  | 9,1          |
| : ---|:------------:|
| Hoe  | 9,1          |
| : ---|:------------:|
| Drill| 7,8          |
</table>
```

I tried to use VLOOKUP(A2; E2:F4; 2; FALSE), but it's don't work

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you have tried and explain the problem you are having with your attempted solution.

Comment: Use `XLOOKUP()` or `INDEX/MATCH` combination.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use a [Lookup function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/lookup-function-446d94af-663b-451d-8251-369d5e3864cb) in the *United Price* cells. I’d suggest making both of them tables. From the image it just looks like loose cells but with tables you can use [structured references](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/using-structured-references-with-excel-tables-f5ed2452-2337-4f71-bed3-c8ae6d2b276e) to make the formulas cleaner and easier to maintain. [image: Lookup formula example]

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2; $E$2:$F$4; 2; FALSE)
```

This will fix the position of the lookup array.